# Word VBA: How to determine a document newly created and modified?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Does anybody know in Word VBA how to determine:

1. A document is newly created;
2. A document is modified by the user?

I found the Document.Saved property, but it does not help in my case.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Document.Path` - if it is an existing document as against a new one.
What do you mean by "it does not help..."?

Comment: I presume he means that Document.Saved is True both for new documents and for documents that have been opened but not modified.

Comment: ...so, Document.Saved on its own is no use. In conjunction with your suggestion, however, it's just the job.

Comment: Yes! Thank you Shahkalpesh, it's just what I want and I didn't noticed that property in the Word Object model CHM document ;) BTW, the structure of that CHM is hard to navigate.

Yes, Gary is correct and that's what I meat :)

Thank you all!

Comment: stackoverflow.com does not recognize line breaks?